# Integrate Office 365 to Window Azure Application?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, azure, azure-sql-database, office365

its might be stupid question to ask here..but Our requirement is window azure application configure to the Office 365. And Fetch Custom List data which is create In Office 365 web application to store in SQL-AZURE SERVER.

m new comer in Window Azure. So I need some help that how to configure its?? Give me Some Direction..plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best choice would be using the SharePoint CSOM to pull data from the O365 and store them into SQL Azure Wictor Wilen did a great post on his blog how to do authentication for O365 from within Azure.

There are many ways how to integrate Windows Azure and O365. I think you have to review such an architectural dicision for each requirement you're face with.

There is a great training course on SharePoint and Azure development. It's not explicitly O365 but hey, it's SharePoint at all :D

Thorsten

Comment: thanks for guide me..i had found solution from http://www.wictorwilen.se/ and approach to solve my solution.